# Converting old MSO coding to External CSS

Tags: css

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:1.5in;text-indent:-1.5in">&nbsp;
```

I inherited an old site created with Frontpage 2000.  I am learning external CSS and converting code.  I don't know what some of the MSO codes mean.

An example (in 79 pages) have that same code in tables.

```
   <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:1.5in;text-indent:-1.5in">&nbsp;
   </p>
   <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:1.5in;text-indent:-1.5in" 
     align="center">&nbsp;</p>
   <div align="center">
   <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="101%">
    <tr>
   <td width="7%" align="center"><b><a href="james-chapel_a.html">A</a> (37)</b>
```

etc. etc.

I have a variety of tables set up in CSS, but converting all the tables on a site with over 1,000 pages is a daunting prospect!

So to start, can I just delete the MSO code above without worrying too much about the original tables?  (until I get more proficient in CSS tables)

Or, should I just leave the 79 pages alone that have this MSO code until I get the tables converted completely to CSS?

Thank you.

Edit:  Let me rephrase the primary question--- What is the MSO code if transferred to external CSS??

Comment: You can simple go page by page & delete these MSO code (inline css) and build up your external css, which can be applied for other tables also. 
After a couple of pages, I think you're good to delete the rest

Comment: See the edit placed in my original post above.

Comment: It will be a collections of selector & styles. For example, `.table { border: 1px solid #000; }`
Then you will re-use this class in any table on your project.